# Cocoa: Is there a way to delete a few files at once?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, file

Is there a way similar to removeItemAtPath: that allows removing of a few files at once? It should not all the files in a directory but can be a few of them only. E.g. you feed the method a few file paths in an array.

Comment: At the end the operating system will anyway delete the files one by one. What stops you from implementing your own small method, doing that? :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a collection of the items you wish to delete, loop over the collection and delete them the same way you'd delete a single file.

Comment: Clear, thank you. I wanted to make sure a method for this does not already exist.